# Django deployment on GoogleCloudPlatform

Tags: python, django

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sa_kQheCnds&t=3384s) tutorial and made sure I'm typing and doing everything perfectly. However I'm on GoogleCloudPlatform and I could see the application while I was running server with 0.0.0.0:8000 but I had to enable/create firewall to let me see it.

My http permissions on Google Cloud Platform is default.

The site just doesn't load and give Gateway Timeout after a while. But even though I run server with 0.0.0.0:8000 I can see the page. Is there any settings I need to enable on GoogleCloudPlatform?

I haven't followed the ufw firewall part in the video though so nothing related to firewall on the server itself.

while running manage.py check --deploy I'm getting these warnings

```
?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.

?: (security.W006) Your SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF setting is not set to True, so your pages will not be served with an 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff' header. You should consider enabling this header to prevent the browser from identifying content types incorrectly.

?: (security.W007) Your SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER setting is not set to True, so your pages will not be served with an 'X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block' header. You should consider enabling this header to activate the browser's XSS filtering and help prevent XSS attacks.

?: (security.W008) Your SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is not set to True. Unless your site should be available over both SSL and non-SSL connections, you may want to either set this setting True or configure a load balancer or reverse-proxy server to redirect all connections to HTTPS.

?: (security.W012) SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is not set to True. Using a secure-only session cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to hijack user sessions.

?: (security.W016) You have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE, but you have not set CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE to True. Using a secure-only CSRF cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to steal the CSRF token.

?: (security.W019) You have 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE, but X_FRAME_OPTIONS is not set to 'DENY'. The default is 'SAMEORIGIN', but unless there is a good reason for your site to serve other parts of itself in a frame, you should change it to 'DENY'.
```

This is the second time happening this even after starting all over again.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting all these warnings with deployment as you are deploying for production mode.
Here is the deployment check follow it and all your warning will be gone.
You have to add the code below into settings.py
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/